# Sending post parameter with Silex test framework

Tags: testing, symfony, phpunit, silex

I have this problem when I try to do functional test on a form submission:

testSearch.php:

```
public function testFormSubmission()
{
   $client = $this->createClient();
   $client->request('POST', '/search', array('nome' => 'Jan'));
   ...
}
```

app.php:

```
$app->post('/search', function (Request $request)  use ($app)
{
    $post_data = $request->get('form');
    ...
});
```

... but $post_data is NULL.

If I do the submission using the submit button in the browser everything works well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `$request->get('form')`, but you didn't set the `form` parameter to anything. Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
$client->request('POST', '/search', array('form' => array('nome' => 'Jan')));
```

If not, you'll need to provide more context.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $client->request('POST', '/search', array('nome' => 'Jan'));
```

the third argument of the request method seems to be for request parameters (?&nome=Jan )

you should use the crawler to simulate a form submission :

from the doc :

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('submit')->form();

// set some values
$form['name'] = 'Lucas';
$form['form_name[subject]'] = 'Hey there!';

// submit the form
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html

or use the sixth parameter to send a raw request body.

Comment: no, this is not the solution, 'form' is not the name of the parameter. When i use the browser in $post_data there's an array like this: array('nome' => 'Jan'). So the parameter is referred by post_data['nome'].

Comment: The third parameter is query string for GET requests, request body for POST/PUT/DELETE/PATCH requests.